# Xampp wont start Apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ip

When trying to start `xampp_start` I get this error:

> Syntax error on line 127 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
>   :
>   The specified IP adress is invalid

Here is my code:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
        Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
     Allow from ::localhost \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16 \

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete apache folder, then redownload it. works perfect now!:)